# Probelm in plotting pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have dataset for authors and respective book title. Sample data as follows:

```
  Author    Title
    A        abc
    B        xyz
    C        pqr
    E        asd
    R        wer
```

I want to plot a graph which should show the frequency of book written by each author.To do that first I am using value_counts() function.

```
books_df.Author.value_counts()
```

and I am getting this output:

```
A    6
C    4
R    3
D    3
E    3
S    1
B    1
Name: Author, dtype: int64
```

I can easily get the bar chart by using following code:

```
plt.bar(books_df.Author.unique(),books_df.Author.value_counts())
```

But when I am trying to generate pie chart using this :

```
plt.pie(books_df.value_counts())
```

I am getting error `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'`

Where I am doing wring?

Expected output:

A pie chart with book ratio and author names AND author with highest number of books should be stand out.

Comment: Try `books_df.Author.value_counts().plot.pie()`?

Comment: Which values do you want to appear in pie chart exactly?

Comment: Note that `plt.bar(books_df.Author.unique(), books_df.Author.value_counts())` doesn't necessarily produce the intended plot. The order of both lists don't need to be the same. Better also use the pandas approach, as suggested by @QuangHoang

Comment: @QuangHoang ohh yes.. I missed Author, Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a silly mistake here. Instead of using  `plt.pie(books_df.value_counts())` you should use `plt.pie(books_df.Author.value_counts())`. You forgot to add 'Author' here.

Now as per your output requirements, You can follow these steps:

1) Create a label with a unique list of authors:

```
label = books_df.Author.value_counts().index
```

2) Create size:

```
sizes = (books_df.Author.value_counts()).tolist()
```

3) To highlight the Author slice with the highest number of books:

```
explode = (0.1, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0)
```

4) To plot the graph:

```
plt.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels,
 autopct='%1.1f%%',shadow=True, startangle=140)

plt.axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

5) You will get something like this:

[image]

Comment: OP is using " books_df.Author.value_counts() " to get the sorted list of all authors with their frequency of books. I think this has to be in the same order. isn't it?

Comment: In that case you should really create the labels from `books_df.Author.value_counts().index`. And not *'with a unique list of authors'*.  Best to save `books_df.Author.value_counts()` into a variable to make sure it is always the same, also in the case of ex-aequo.

Comment: @JohanC I got your point, here I am making label variable manually which would not work for any random Book_df.